# Is there a R function for finding an index of an element in a vector?

Tags: r, indexing, match, vectorization

In R, I have an element x and a vector v. I want to find the first index of an element in v that is equal to x. I know that one way to do this is:

```
which(x == v)[[1]]
```

but that seems excessively inefficient. Is there a more direct way to do it?

For bonus points, is there a function that works if x is a vector? That is, it should return a vector of indices indicating the position of each element of x in v.

Comment: You're looking for `match()`, `match(x, v)`